# Gremlin-python - how to automate graph creation

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm trying to create on EC2 with Amazon Linux 2 a python script to create a graph on neptune AWS.

```
from __future__  import print_function

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

graph = Graph()

remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection('wss://myendpoint:8182/gremlin','g')
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)

def list_all(self, limit=500):
    g.V().limit(limit).elementMap().toList()

def find_vertex(self, vid):
    g.V(vid).elementMap().next()

def list_by_label_name(self, vlabel, name):
    g.V().has(vlabel, 'name', name).elementMap().toList()


vertices = g.V().groupCount().toList()
edges  = g.E().groupCount().toList()

print(vertices)
print(edges)


# Find up to 15 routes from LHR to SJC that make one stop.
paths = g.V() \
             .out().out().has('table').limit(15) \
             .path().by('table').toList()



# Create a new empty DiGraph
G=nx.DiGraph()

# Add the routes we found to DiGraph we just created
for p in paths:
    G.add_edge(p[0],p[1])
    G.add_edge(p[1],p[2])


# Give the starting and ending airports a different color
colors = []

for label in G:
    if label in['table']:
        colors.append('yellow')
    else:
        colors.append('#11cc77')

# Now draw the graph
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
nx.draw(G, node_color=colors, node_size=1200, with_labels=True)
plt.show()


remoteConn.close()
```

no issue to connect to neptune but with **import matplotlib.pyplot as plt** I have an issue when I run the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gremlinexample.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 63, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

I tried to install Tkinter with

```
$ pip install tk
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tk in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.1.0)
```

and with

```
$ pip3 install tk
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tk in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.0)
```

but I have always the same problem

My goals is to draw a neptune graph with a python script. I don't want to use a neptune notebook because I want to build my graph for a web app that calls a python script

Comment: Fo a web app, you may want to also look at wrappers like PyVis that wrap Vis.js and can create HTML. Such visuals will be a lot more dynamic/interactive than those created by MatPlotLib or TKInter. There are also Python libraries that wrap Cytoscape and D3.

Comment: Thanks @KelvinLawrence. Is there a solution to call Neptune notebook (where I have my graph) remotely with script/other and show the graph without create an HTML?

Comment: The Jupyter Notebooks are really designed to be accessed via a Jupyter server (which could be Amazon SageMaker or your own hosting of Jupyter). You can invoke cells programmatically from other cells but there is not really any support for embedding the notebook in other applications.  The graph-notebook project is open source in case you want to study how the notebooks draw diagrams.